# Why is my for loop not getting all the results in a dict with json parameters?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to extract certain items from a json dict but when I print it, it only prints a random one from it and not all the possible items. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

This is an example of the dic:

```
{'request_hash': 'request:search:ebd66e81d77d207550efbdf3ff068c39ead7915c', 'request_cached': True, 'request_cache_expiry': 430532, 'results': [{'image_url': 'https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/9/77809.jpg?s=5e4f31284abea2059db7fe1b07ff1fa5', 'title': 'Noragami', 'airing': False, 'type': 'TV', 'episodes': 12, 'score': 7.99}, {'image_url': 'https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/1689/94850.jpg?s=fab6fe8f945df387aa69be2dc6c48870', 'title': 'Noragami Aragoto', 'airing': False, 'type': 'TV', 'episodes': 13, 'score': 8.2}
```

My intention is to get all the titles with their respective image_url and episodes but when I try my code I only get a random one like this:

```
[{'Title': 'Sakura Taisen: Katsudou Shashin', 'Episodes': 1, 'Image': 'https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/13/20234.jpg?s=7d8ef8872e34c7423b8f1273cf79dbc3'}]
```

I basically want that result but from ALL the possibilities, since the results list more than one and that's where my code is not working.
This is my code that's not looping correctly:

```
animes = []

results = r.json()
results = results['results']
        
if len(results):
    for result in results:
        animes_data = {
                    
                    'Title' : result["title"],
                    'Episodes' : result["episodes"],
                    'Image' : result["image_url"]
                }
       animes.append(animes_data)  
        
else:
    message = print("No results found")
```

I had to write this: results = results['results']  because otherwise it would give me a string error. So how can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Just stick to `results = results['results']` because that's how the JSON you received is laid out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
animes = {'request_hash': 'request:search:ebd66e81d77d207550efbdf3ff068c39ead7915c', 'request_cached': True, 'request_cache_expiry': 430532, 'results': [{'image_url': 'https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/9/77809.jpg?s=5e4f31284abea2059db7fe1b07ff1fa5', 'title': 'Noragami', 'airing': False, 'type': 'TV', 'episodes': 12, 'score': 7.99}, {'image_url': 'https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/1689/94850.jpg?s=fab6fe8f945df387aa69be2dc6c48870', 'title': 'Noragami Aragoto', 'airing': False, 'type': 'TV', 'episodes': 13, 'score': 8.2}]}

results = animes['results']
output = []

for result in results:
    animes_data = {

        'Title' : result["title"],
        'Episodes' : result["episodes"],
        'Image' : result["image_url"]
    }
    output.append(animes_data)


[print(json.dumps(item, indent=4)) for item in output]
```